# Collection in java that can disappear in scene builder

Tags: java, scenebuilder

I am making a collection of button and text field in java. Whenever one of the button is pressed, i want to make the collection invisible/disappear. Is it possible? What collection should i use?

Answer (score 1):

All the buttons and text fields whom you want to make invisible ,keep inside a JPanel. Now when the desired button is pressed you want to make `jpanel.setvisible(false)`. 
Write this code inside the `ActionListener` of that particular button

Comment: Thanks for the help and fast response. Good day to you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. How to make if an imageview is pressed, the image will disappear. I only know how for when a button is pressed.. please help :(

Comment: Hi bro,,,though I have never worked on Android ,generically I suggest you write set the image invisible on event listener of that image view..Plz see the link..it might be helpful...http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/